# Laptop gets slower as it runs

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, thinkpad

Right after I reboot, the laptop works normally, but the more it runs, the more it slows down, and I have to reboot after every couple hours. It's almost as if there's a memory leak somewhere. This is what I have

```
ThinkPad-T520:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic


ThinkPad-T520:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.7G        2.8G        136M        452M        863M        869M
Swap:           33G        471M         33G



ThinkPad-T520:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           383M  6.5M  377M   2% /run
/dev/sda6       189G  153G   27G  85% /
tmpfs           1.9G  290M  1.6G  16% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/5145
/dev/loop1       87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4917
/dev/loop2      163M  163M     0 100% /snap/spotify/13
/dev/loop3      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/skype/45
/dev/loop8      173M  173M     0 100% /snap/spotify/19
/dev/loop7      142M  142M     0 100% /snap/skype/51
/dev/loop6      144M  144M     0 100% /snap/skype/48
/dev/loop5      163M  163M     0 100% /snap/spotify/16
/dev/loop4       87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4830
tmpfs           383M  132K  383M   1% /run/user/1000

ThinkPad-T520:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [Quadro NVS 4200M] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)
0d:00.0 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd PCIe SDXC/MMC Host Controller (rev 08)
0d:00.3 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 PCIe IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 04)
```

As suggested, I also tried

```
ThinkPad-T520:~$ ps -e -o stat,pcpu,command | grep -E '^[^ ]*(R|D)'
R     0.0 [kworker/1:2]
R+    0.0 ps -e -o stat,pcpu,command
```

I also ran

```
ThinkPad-T520:~$ grep . -r /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/ff_gbl_lock:       0  EN     enabled      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe15:       0     STS invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe05:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe3F:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe33:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe2F:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe23:       0     STS invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe1F:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe13:       0     STS invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe0F:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe03:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe3D:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe31:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe2D:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe21:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe1D:       0  EN     enabled      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe11:    1230  EN     enabled      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/ff_pwr_btn:       0  EN     enabled      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/ff_slp_btn:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe0D:       0         disabled     unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe01:       0  EN     enabled      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/ff_pmtimer:       0     STS invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe3B:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe2B:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe1B:       0     STS invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe38:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe0B:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe28:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe18:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe08:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/sci:    1233
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe36:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe26:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/error:       0
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe16:       0  EN     enabled      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe06:       3  EN     enabled      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/ff_rt_clk:       0         disabled     unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe34:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe24:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe14:       0     STS invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe04:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe3E:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe32:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe2E:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe22:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe1E:       0     STS invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe12:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe0E:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe02:       0  EN     enabled      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe3C:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe30:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe2C:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe20:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe1C:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe10:       0     STS invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe39:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe0C:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe00:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe3A:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe29:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe2A:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe19:       0     STS invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe1A:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe09:       0         disabled     unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe37:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe0A:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe27:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe17:       0     STS invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/sci_not:       0
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe07:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe35:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe25:       0         invalid      unmasked
/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe_all:    1233
```

Top gives me

```
ThinkPad-T520:~$ top

top - 16:43:00 up 56 min,  1 user,  load average: 1.41, 1.09, 0.47
Tasks: 231 total,   1 running, 230 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1.1 us,  0.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 96.3 id,  2.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  3919592 total,   518592 free,  1786336 used,  1614664 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 35530744 total, 35530744 free,        0 used.  1842628 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND     
 4102 myUsername    20   0   46644   3984   3360 R   6.2  0.1   0:00.02 top         
    1 root      20   0  220904   8768   6480 S   0.0  0.2   0:01.64 systemd     
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd    
    4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:+ 
    6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_+ 
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.02 ksoftirqd/0 
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.63 rcu_sched   
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh      
   10 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0 
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 watchdog/0  
   12 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0     
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1     
   14 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/1  
   15 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/1 
   16 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 ksoftirqd/1 
   18 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:+ 
   19 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/2
```

Comment: have you checked top for any runaway process' ?

Comment: Make sure your laptop is not overheating. Make sure the fan is working properly, that it is not clogged, etc.

Comment: also `ps -e -o stat,pcpu,command | grep -E '^[^ ]*(R|D)'`

Comment: How do I check for a runaway process? When I run top, I don't see anything occupying a lot of resources.

How do I check and fix the fan? Any detailed instructions? Anything else I can take care of hardware-wise?

Comment: Can you post the output of top as well? Last edit i swear. Can you also post the output of `grep . -r /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts`

Comment: You could, perodically, `ps -ejHly >ps.log.$( date +%y%b%d-%H%M%S )`, and `diff` the log files later.

Comment: Sure, please see edits above.

Comment: `/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe11:    1230  EN     enabled      unmasked` you might try disabling this at boot and see if this fixes anyting? `echo "disable" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpeXX` Disabling random ACPI interrupts could cause all kinds of problems, so do this at your own risk.